# How to unit test KeyNotFoundException without assigning dictionary value

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, dictionary, keynotfoundexception

I wish to run a unit test on a particular dictionary in my code, trying to get a value I don't expect to be in the database (in this case, key=1).

I have written the following code:

```
    Try
        Dim s As String = myDict(1)
    Catch ex As KeyNotFoundException
        Assert.AreEqual("The given key was not present in the dictionary.", ex.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Assert.Fail()
        Throw
    End Try
```

which works fine, but the code analysis is complaining about the "Dim s as String" declaration, as it says that s will never be used for anything. Well that's intentional, because I *intend* for this to throw an exception and s is irrelevant.

However, I can't seem to find a way to eliminate s from the code. Simply removing the assignment:

```
    Try
        myDict(1)
    Catch ex As KeyNotFoundException
        Assert.AreEqual("The given key was not present in the dictionary.", ex.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Assert.Fail()
        Throw
    End Try
```

now fails to compile. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can do this by putting a line after the dictionary call which uses the s variable:

```
    Try
        Dim s As String = theDocumentsWithUserNameDictDto.Dict(1)
        Assert.Fail("Found unexpected value for dictionary key 1: " & s)
    Catch ex As KeyNotFoundException
        Assert.AreEqual("The given key was not present in the dictionary.", ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I still don't expect the variable to be used (if the test passes), but this does have the benefit of providing extra clarity to the user if the test does fail for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is really no way to fix this in typed code.  The call `myDict(1)` is an indexer and it's not legal as a statement (also illegal in C#).  In order to test this you will need to use this expression as a part of legal statement.

One way to accomplish this is pass the value as a parameter to a method which doesn't use it

```
Sub Unused(ByVal o As Object)

End Sub

...

Unused(myDict(1))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this just moves the warning further downstream: I'm now getting "Parameter 'o' of 'RealDataContextTest.Unused(Object)' is never used" :)

Comment: @bobsmith833 what tool are you using?  The compiler shouldn't emit this warning.  Either way I'd just mark the warning as suppressed on this method.  Let it become the default "I explicitly don't want to use this" method

Comment: It's just the standard Code Analysis but I've set it to "Microsoft All Rules". As you say, that's probably overkill but was interested to see if there was an easy way to eliminate this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using NUnit Framework than

you could use the following code

```
  Dim f As Func(Of Integer, String) = Function(i) myDict.Item(i)
  Dim a As TestDelegate = Function() f(1)
  Dim ex As KeyNotFoundException = Assert.Throws(Of KeyNotFoundException)(a)
  Assert.AreEqual("The given key was not present in the dictionary.", ex.Message)
```

This is a similar solution which is proposed by JaredPar

Another option is to make the test returning a value and use the `ExpectedException` attribute so the code could look like this:

```
<TestCase(New Object(0  - 1) {}, Result:=Nothing), ExpectedException(GetType(KeyNotFoundException), ExpectedMessage:="The given key was not present in the dictionary."), Test> _
Public Function MyTest() As String
  Return myDict.Item(1)
End Function
```